# customizing speedbar for custom headers

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I've been keeping note files with the following header

```
###--- section
##-- subsection
#- subsubsection
```

Is there a way to customize speedbar to navigate over these? Right now M-x speedbar just gives me directory listing. So far I've been using "M-x occur #-" for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple derived mode and imenu.  For example, suppose your notes are in files with the extension ".notes":

```
(define-derived-mode notes-mode text-mode "notes"
  "Mode for editing my notes."
  (setq imenu-generic-expression (list '(nil "^\\s-*[#]+[-]+\\s-*\\(.+\\)" 1))))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.notes" . notes-mode))

(eval-after-load "speedbar"
  '(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".notes"))
```

The regexp is a bit crude, but you get the idea.  You could font-lock the headers too if you want to make them stand out.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I guess if I want sections to be nested and collapsible I need to use something like etags?

Comment: Sounds like you guys are getting ready to invent org-mode.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `-*- mode: outline-mode; outline-regexp: "#+" -*-` on the first line of your file (together with the `(eval-after-load "speedbar" '(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".notes"))` suggested by scottfrazer) and you should be set.

But as event_jr mentions, you might be better off renaming your file with a ".org" extension and replacing your "#" chars with "*".

Org-mode is basically a (much larger) superset of outline-mode.